# How to use .match() when I'm trying to loop through an object?

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I'm trying to test my site navigation against what I have in a config file. I was getting a failure and determined the failure was because my config had title case but the DOM has upper case. I'd like the tests to be case agnostic as I find it easier to read a config file with title case. I'm sure I could do a .toLowerCase() or a .toUpperCase() or something, but seems to me like it would be best to try and use .match(). I'm not quite sure how to use it properly when trying to use it in a loop through object keys.

Sample Config:

```
"mainMenuNavTopLevel": {
        "Oneword": "/path1",
        "Two Words": "/path2"
    },
```

Sample Test:

```
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(config.mainMenuNavTopLevel)) {
            let caseKey = key.match(/`"${key}"/i)  // this doesn't seem to work

            // Verify the top menu nav items displayed match the keys in the object in config
            await t.expect(Header.mainMenuNavItem.withText(caseKey).exists).ok(`"${caseKey}" Main Menu Nav key does NOT match config`);
```

Line 24 errors with
`"text" argument is expected to be a string or a regular expression, but it was object.`

How would I go about using match in this case? Is it even possible?

Comment: What is this supposed to be **`"${key}"** ? A [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) ?

Comment: @Titus Forgive me. I'm still learning. It's supposed to be a reference to the object's key. I copied it from the .ok(...) part of the await. I'm sure that doesn't really make sense. It's the only thing I knew how to at least try.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do but try: `..Header.mainMenuNavItem.withText(new RegExp(key, 'i'))..`

Comment: @Titus I believe that has worked. Thank you!